# Transfer files to new directories

Tags: php, variables, directory, file-transfer, user-registration

I just need a simple code to transfer files to new directories that will have variable names.

for instance here is a snip of my code, it is very simple, see the attachment

As you can see this is a registration page, when the user is created, then a token is created a folder is created with the username which is a variable in this case, in the end, it created the folder and finally sends a confirmation email via php mailer.

I want once the folder I mentioned earlier is created post user registration it needs to automatically copy all files (*.*) located in: temp/accounts/profile into the new directory created, for instance:

temp/accounts/profile/newuser

I tried to do this but since the new directory relies on the username input it is a variable and I'm not sure how to build this query to transfer the files successfully after user registration.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Loop the contents from one directory and copy them over to the new one.

```
$targetDir = 'temp/accounts/profile/newuser';
//of course create this folder first if it doesn't exist
mkdir($targetDir);

// Scan the directory and retrieve all files
// `array_diff` is to clean out directory thingies than can persist
foreach(array_diff(scandir($dirname), ['.','..']) as $val){

   copy("$dirname/$val", "$targetDir/$val");

}
```

Comment: I tested your code and the (newuser) refers to the new username registered based on the $name variable, the code you provided is creating a new directory called "newuser" which is unexpected, As previously mentioned I can create the directory successfully using:

$dirname = "temp/accounts/profile/".$name;
mkdir($dirname);

However once the new directory is created we have been unable to transfer all the files in"
temp/accounts/profile into the new directory created. Again, the directory is created with the ""username"" but the folder is empty.

Comment: If it's a linux-type machine, do you have permission to move files?

And what does scandir($dirname) return?

Answer (score 0):

You need to find all files and copy them over one by one. If you need to copy directories you'll have to implement a recursive copy, in that case, you could use [is_dir](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php) within your loop to check if the filename is a directory.

```
<?php
$source = 'temp/accounts/profile/newuser';
$destination = 'temp/accounts/profile/' . $name;
$files = glob($source . "/*.*"); //Find all files
foreach($files as $filename){
    copy($filename, $destination . "/" . basename($filename));
}
?>
```